# using templateUrl angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('home', []);

app.controller('articleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "elad";
    $scope.writer = "elad";
    $scope.content = "bla bla bla bla bla";
}]);

app.directive('drArticle', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/app/shared/article/Views/articleView.html'
    };
});
```

The `templateUrl` is trying to access the html file via this url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:56911/app/componenets/home/app/shared/article/Views/articleView.html
```

The file is actually located at :

`http://127.0.0.1:56911/app/componenets/home/views/index.html`

How can I fix the path to be like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:56911/app/shared/article/Views/articleView.html
```

Comment: what about templateUrl: '../../../app/shared/article/Views/articleView.html'
Not tried it before myself

Comment: I guess you're creating build using gulp/grunt and from the multiple js file for the application it's creating a single file and as the folder structure is getting changed you're not getting the template.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this way?

```
templateUrl: currentScriptPath('articleView.html')
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry I forgot to add some code, the result should be this:

```
var currentScriptPath = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;

var app = angular.module('home',[]);

app.controller('articleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.title = "elad";
    $scope.writer = "elad";
    $scope.content ="bla bla bla bla bla";

}]);

app.directive('drArticle', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: currentScriptPath('articleView.html')
    };
});
```